# Spring Boot Failed to Convert JSON to pojo from POST request for fields that are not of type string

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

```
 public class Dog {
   private String name;
   private int weight;
     //...getters and
    //setters and constructor 
 }
```

Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/dogs", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
 produces = "application/json")
 public void createDog(Dog dog) {
    dr.save(dog); 
 }
```

How come when I call the endpoint with json `{"name":"bark", "weight":50}`
I get an error:

> Failed to convert value of type 'null' to required type 'int'; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
> convert from type [null] to type [int] for value 'null'; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A null value cannot
> be assigned to a primitive type",
> "objectName": "dog",
> "field": "weight",
> "rejectedValue": null,
> "bindingFailure": true,
> "code": "typeMismatch"
>
> "message": "Validation failed for object='dog'. Error count: 1

edit: I get the same issue with booleans and doubles. I guess I have to use objects not primitives?

Answer (score 9):

Add the annotation `@RequestBody` to the param `dog` in your `create` method

Comment: Ah. Thanks. 15char

Comment: That's true. I was only missing this notation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Need to specify the `@RequestBody` annotation to specify we are sending DOG object as part of request body:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dogs", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json") 
public void createDog((**@RequestBody** Dog dog) { dr.save(dog); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Only works with objects so use Integer instead of int.

Answer (score 0):

If exist possibility object receive null, you can't use type primitives, same int, char, boolean.

```
private int weight
```

Use type objects same Integer, Boolean ... for one type primitive has a Object, then can receive null value.